# C pointer manipulation for strings gives unexpected output

Tags: c, string, pointers, c-strings

The following two programs use some basic pointer manipulation. But they perform differently.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
     int a = 1;
     int b = 2;
     int *pb, *pc;
     pb = &a;
     pc = pb;
     pb = &b;
     printf("%d %d\n", *pb, *pc);
}
```

This program prints two different numbers(1 and 2) as expected while,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
     char *ptr, s[10];
     ptr = s;
     gets(s);
     printf("%s %s\n", ptr, s);
}
```

This program prints the same string two times, whereas it also must have printed different strings.

Why this difference?

How does gets() read a string?

Comment: "it must have"... what? Why?

Comment: I have a feeling that you have no idea what pointers really are...

Comment: "whereas it also must have printed different strings" -- nonsense; it will obviously print the same string twice. "Why this difference?" -- because they are completely different programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example only contains a single string buffer, the array `s`.

Making `ptr` point to `s` doesn't in any way create a second copy of the character data, so when you print both `ptr` and `s`, they result in the same string since they evaluate to the exact same address.

Answer (score 1):

After your code runs this:

```
ptr = s;
```

`ptr` points to the beginning of `s`, so when you invoke `printf()` you get the same address passed twice there - no wonder the same is being printed twice.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example you have only *one* array (`s`) plus a second pointer pointing to the same memory. The two addresses `ptr` and `s` are identical and so of course using then in `printf()` results in the same output. In your first example you have two different integers which can hold different values.

Answer (score 1):

Because those two character pointers are still pointing to the same memory. You are just assigning data to the pointed memory.

But in the case of that integer pointer, you are changed the memory address pointed by the first pointer.

If you did like this:

```
pb  = &a;
pc  = pb;
*pb = 7;
```

It'll print 7 in both case. This is what you did with the character pointer.

---

Explanation with images:

When you did pb = &a; pb will point to the memory address of a.

[image: pb = &a]

When you did pc = pb; pb & pc will point to the memory address of a.

[image: pc = pb]

When you did pb = &b; pb will point to the memory address of b. But pc will still point to memory address of a.

[image: pb = &b]

**Disclaimer:** I have attached images with the answer, there is some technical issues in SO. That is why the 3 images are not showing. Check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186466/intermittent-error-with-imgur-when-uploading-images

Answer (score 0):

> This program prints the same string two times, whereas it also must have printed different strings.

It mustn't. In your first example, the pointers point to different objects. In the second one, the explicit pointer and the one `s` decays into point to the same array in memory (obviously...)